# Spring Boot War File Tomcat 9 Deployment Help Status 500 Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, web-deployment

UPDATE 8/12/2020 approx. 11:00 AM - I checked my logs folder catalina.2020-08-12.log log in the tomcat9 ($CATALINA_BASE) folder and I found three exceptions "org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler intialization failed", "java.net.BindException: Address already in use (bind failed)","java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the HTTP protocol [HTTP/1.10x0aHost:]".
Here is the full error log here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pSk5ESHLIRP5Srxwr4R1Tp_1TTcYMf2Y/view?usp=sharing and https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C-RALR3066_hYKeoo4dIJqTKwNDOQ0R0/view?usp=sharing.

UPDATE 8/12/2020 approx. 11:30 AM - I found that there are two servlet dispatchers running by checking the localhost.2020-08-12.log log when I restarted tomcat and tried to access my api again: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GFKUIDLtZrAraHyMjyyWV9kXK33gQ-Mu/view?usp=sharing.

UPDATE 8/12/2020 approx. 11:35 AM - HA HAAAA I looked in the catalina.out log (finally some of you guys were probably yelling at the screen like "CHECK THE CATALINA.OUT FILE"). I checked it and I found the exception: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required": https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A7ZLh70IHOmWXfQ56bgtq951EE_AX68P/view?usp=sharing.  Now if I go to my PostgresDataSource class which is where my Hikari config is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lYN1dTqiAM4ZqliRGC5J5_VWhNeN-k2d/view?usp=sharing, and I review my application.yaml file from earlier: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xvPhPneVjMU4BoN6F0Q63l2wCnF20BYq/view?usp=sharing, the jdbc url is present because it is the same one I used for developing.  Now postgres is already set up and I manually made all of the tables on the ubuntu droplet.  I did not download the jdbc postgresql driver for tomcat yet.

UPDATE 8/12/2020 approx. 1:20 PM - After setting up the jdbc driver now I get this error from catalina.out logs: " Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=java:/comp/env/jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/****" and then I get "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver".  I used the postgresql section of this link to set it up: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html.

Hi I am using Digital Ocean with apache tomcat 9 to deploy a war file that is generated using IntelliJ.  I have the war file generated using mvn clean install and I get the default tomcat page when I go to the droplet IP address on port 8080.  I am not sure why I get a 500 error with no stack trace information even though my spring boot application works fine when I run it in IntelliJ.  My CSS styling also does not show up when I go to my hosted application I have tried to configure a few things in my application.yml file and it still does not work.  I figured it might have to do with a spring security issue with CORS, but I am not knowledgeable enough in that area to know for sure.  I started my server by using sudo $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh and it said tomcat started and it showed the default tomcat page when I went there in the browser. I used the hobynapi.war file in my target folder a picture of my target folder directory can be viewed here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XXga1Bgf5-_81gceuWjpvVIX6J0jiNgQ/view?usp=sharing.  I copied the war file that was generated after using mvn clean install to the /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps folder.  I then ran sudo $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh again and it ran tomcat successfully again.  Then the error happened as I tried to log in with the admin account with spring security basic authentication where I get the 500 error.  I also have no artifacts in the artifact section of the project structure settings if that means anything.

UPDATE 8/12/2020 approx. 10:00 AM - I've removed the exclusions tag in the pom.xml file as well as the profiles tag at the bottom of the file.  This is because I read here that using the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency removes the embedded server for you: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/04/16/spring-boot-tomcat.

This is the screen without the CSS styling that should be there:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CEKuB556ek8pTZspvprNTa9M5XCI7qtT/view?usp=sharing

This is the error I get without a stack trace:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19gYGQFhZdZ_4IwwGE5tQzb4dTqlBpg9L/view?usp=sharing

These are pictures of my pom.xml file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ir5uBuBuJqCb_U8Jarly9mraO468QA_y/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ma1_EPro4NvJiOy8lWPrAmGLMrVWHZPS/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11NDIwA9g02zkCKnsmYSLSNF5R-BrFpgt/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p6T9-oOwyfj7NUsLxTRLtqXKHU4qHrZx/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1spD7KT-3WBo7KFF0Hb_WgJ5dVKRHF-un/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16QtJQtT9zaU7nGcpnm2KXJ6jiLywNt5s/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cnZJshFS5xW-HbeaH_C_e6KcDo9xYRdY/view?usp=sharing

This is my application.yml file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xvPhPneVjMU4BoN6F0Q63l2wCnF20BYq/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B9_5WueRvqQv4ODsJAfbUzGIm-xaaSYV/view?usp=sharing

This is my main application java file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K9lzzlzIKT8irqXsPY1WeiBvN-9vsoWT/view?usp=sharing

This is my web config file in my config package:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19EYa2kkqqPu9Wh8nN-U02szSVBT30lOP/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11Zw8dLrAu6c_OI29j0NsljvXdeDam0-t/view?usp=sharing

This is my spring security config file in my config package:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1inqlTjfxahcF6ZeJ_xkJM18UgsDu119n/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nTeYiKhiNOH71Km-s_T4IT1BKRyJG4mS/view?usp=sharing

I hope that these pictures help for diagnosing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  First I changed the postgres jdbc url back to the original one that I had and then I altered my data source config file to the following: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zmv8cfnVzW8NcQfjNxN14D4aKFaXpdfU/view?usp=sharing.  One important thing I also messed up on was not setting a password for the default user "postgres" when downloading postgresql.  I did this my calling "ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'myPassword';" in the postgresql command line. Also make sure that you use systemctl restart postgresql after any changes are made to postgresql in the postgresql command line.